# BFS Tree Traversal

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to write a Breadth-First-Search algorithm in Javascript that also includes the number of repetitions of every node.  For example, in a videogame crafting menu, I want to craft a desired item A that requires items B x20, C x30, and D x100.  Items B, C, and D in turn require other items times another arbitrary amount.  I want to know how many of the items at the bottommost level of the tree I would need in order to craft item A.  Try as I might, I cannot find a solution for this.  Basically, I am doing a BFS of the materials and a BFS of the material amounts "in parallel".  The intended output is a 2D array (2 rows, x columns) with the (unique) material names in the first row and the associated material amounts in the second row.  This current code gives me a blank result.  I've written 10-20 variations of it by now over the course of 8 weeks after having searched StackOverflow, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java/, and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript.  No luck, or I am just so new to JS that I don't see an answer that's right in front of me.  All of the functions I have called from this function work perfectly (I tested them separately).

```
function traversebreadth(key, keyamt, leaveschecked, repschecked, leavesqueue, repsqueue, roots, leaves, leafreps) { //initial parameters: string, number, [], [], string (same as key), number (same as keyamt), Array (column vector), 2D array (each row is a material list corresponding to the same row in "roots"), 2D array (each row is a material amount list corresponding to the same row in both "roots" and "leaves")

  var keyleaves = getleaves(key, roots, leaves);    //gets the leaves(/children) of the current node
  var keyreps = getleafreps(key, roots, leafreps);  //gets the children of the current node's repetitions (or "amounts")
  keyreps = scalarmultiply(keyamt, keyreps);        //multiplies the current repetitions by the number of repetitions of the parent node

  leaveschecked += key;   //push the key to the queue of checked nodes
  repschecked += keyamt;  //push the keyamt to the queue of checked node reps

  if(!Array.isArray(leavesqueue)){  //ensure leavesqueue is an Object (Array), not a Number
        var lq = [];
        lq.push(leavesqueue);
        leavesqueue = lq;
  }
  if(!Array.isArray(repsqueue)){    //ensure repsqueue is an Object (Array), not a Number
        var rq = [];
        rq.push(repsqueue);
        repsqueue = rq;
  }
  if(isemptyarray(leavesqueue,"row")){      //if leavesqueue is empty, then there are no more leaves to check and this recursive function can return the result
        return ArrayLib.transpose(leaveschecked).concat(ArrayLib.transpose(repschecked));  //return all of the unique nodes needed to craft item A, and the total amount of each node
  }else{                                    //else, repeat this function
        var newleavesqueue = queueleaves(keyleaves, leavesqueue); //queueleaves() appends keyleaves to leavesqueue and removes the first element of leavesqueue, then returns leavesqueue
        var newrepsqueue = queueleafreps(keyreps,repsqueue); //queueleafreps() does the same thing as queueleaves() using keyreps and repsqueue
        var newkey = ArrayLib.transpose(newleavesqueue).shift();   //gets the new node to use as current key
        var newkeyamt = ArrayLib.transpose(newrepsqueue).shift();  //gets the reps of this new current key
        traversebreadth(newkey, newkeyamt, leaveschecked, repschecked, newleavesqueue, newrepsqueue, roots, leaves, leafreps);  //repeat this function with the new parameters
}
```

Comment: So it's not a *tree* traversal, but rather a DAG traversal?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with a DAG traversal, but from what I can tell by the Wikipedia article on it, a DAG is not what I am trying to do.  My intent is a BFS.

Comment: OK, I must have misunderstood what you meant by "repetitions". I thought that e.g. both C and D would depend on an item E - a shared dependency. Which would make your input a DAG instead of a tree.

Comment: Can you please post a small JSON-formatted example of the input data?

Comment: "*The intended output is a 2D array (2 rows, x columns) with the (unique) material names in the first row and the associated material amounts in the second row*" - I would recommend not to do that. Rather output an array of objects, each object having a property with the unique name and a property with the amount. That should be much easier to deal with. If necessary, transform this into your two arrays in the end.

Comment: Yeah, I concatenate the arrays at the end of the recursion (or what should be the end of it) in this line:

return ArrayLib.transpose(leaveschecked).concat(ArrayLib.transpose(repschecked));